# Variables in nginx with regex are empty

Tags: nginx

I have this code in nginx and I need to redirect different paths to the corresponding file, such as:

```
/apple-touch-icon.png
/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png
/en/apple-touch-icon.png
/en/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png
/en-us/apple-touch-icon.png
/en-us/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png
```

And the icons are inside the `/assets/` folder

I have a condition to prevent nginx from looping when it makes a redirect to the `assets` folder

```
location ~* ^/([a-zA-Z-]+/)?(apple-touch-icon(-[0-9]+x[0-9]+)?(-precomposed)?\.png)$ {
  if ($uri !~ ^/assets/$2) {
    return 301 /assets/$2;
  }
}
```

But variable `$1` gives me this error

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown "1" variable
```

and variable `$2` is empty

Any idea how I can make this code work? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each regular expression overwrites the numeric captures of the previous regular expression when it is evaluated by Nginx. If it contains no parentheses (no captures), the associated numeric variables will be empty.

So, your `if` block is a second regular expression that resets all of the numeric captures generated by the first, which means that your first `$2` contains the value from the `location` statement, and the second `$2` is empty.

The problem with your regular expressions can be solved with a named capture, for example: `(?<name> ... )` and then use it later as `$name`.

The problem with your example can be solved by adding a specific `location` to handle URIs that begin with `/assets/`, for example:

```
location ~* ^/([a-zA-Z-]+/)?(apple-touch-icon(-[0-9]+x[0-9]+)?(-precomposed)?\.png)$ {
    return 301 /assets/$2;
}
location ^~ /assets/ {
}
```

Notice the `^~` operator which means this *prefix location* has precedence over any *regular expression location*. See [location manual page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).